# Not able to create ChromeDriver object

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

My Selenium code is failing.When I run the code a blank chrome browser is opening but after that the error is throwing, Can anyone please help me..

The same code was running fine before 1 months.

**Code using to create ChromeDriver**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Windows\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver1 = new ChromeDriver(); //throwing the error here
    driver1.manage().window().maximize();
    driver1.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60 * 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

**Console**

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4) on port 46687
Only local connections are allowed.
Apr 01, 2017 8:33:16 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: 'XXX', ip: 'XXX.XXX.X.XXX', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:174)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:120)
    at com.led.scrapper.main.Starter.main(Starter.java:36)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:155)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:284)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:165)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:64)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    ... 8 more
```

**Maven Dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**Chrome Driver Version**

```
2.21
```

Comment: Please mention version of chrome browser and selenium that you are using, then it may help us to answer

Comment: Have you checked to see if there's another instance of chromedriver running?

Comment: @socalcheesehead there is not other instance running.. Is it something to do with windows 10?

Comment: I just suggested that because sometimes you see that error or a bind error if there's another instance running. Perhaps a runaway process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking into your error message,I understand you are using old version of chrome driver.

If you are using latest chrome browser versions, you need to get latest chrome driver from below mentioned url.

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

In my machine chrome driver 2.27 working fine with chrome browser version 56.

Let me know if you have any queries

Comment: Let me know which version of chrome browser and chrome driver you tried?

Comment: Chrome browser version is 56.xx and Chrome driver is 2.27

Comment: to be exact.. this is the chrome browser version..
57.0.2987.133

Comment: Finally I figured out the issue.. The old and new drivers were placed in the same directtory with names `chromedriver.exe` and `chromedriver_.exe`, it worked after deleting `chromedriver_.exe`.. looks weird, but it fixed my issue

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.

The problem was i was using

```
Chrome Driver 2.9
Chrome version 60
selenium version 3.4
```

I was under the impression that 2.9 is latest version of Chrome Driver however when i used 2.7 it got resolved.

Now i am using

```
Chrome Driver 2.7
Chrome version 60
selenium version 3.4
```

Hope it helps.